# The Index of first column (_id) = -1

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get the data of column "_id" (which is the first column) , name and password columns **(Total 3 columns)**

but I got this error message

**Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow...**

so I run a test to get the the number of columns using getColumnCount() but it return **2**

after that I started to get the index of all columns and I found that **"_id"** column returns value **(-1)** and that's why I get that error message

I looked into my query statement but there is nothing wrong with it.

can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
    public class SQLiteAdapter {

        SQLiteHelper helper;

        public SQLiteAdapter(Context context) {
            helper = new SQLiteHelper(context);
        }

        public String getAllData() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

            // select _id, name, password from ahmadssbdb
            String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.COL_NAME, SQLiteHelper.COL_PASSWORD };

            Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,
                    null, null, null);

            StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            int indexUID = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_ID);
            int indexColName = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_NAME);
            int indexColPassword = cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.COL_PASSWORD);
            String uid = " " + indexUID + " " + indexColName + " "  + indexColPassword;
            return uid;


        /*************************************
         *  Retrieve  data from each column 
         *************************************/

        /*
         * while(cursor.moveToNext()){
         * 
         * long uid = cursor.getInt(indexUID); 
         * String name = cursor.getString(indexColName);
         * String password = cursor.getString(indexColPassword); 
         * strBuffer.append(uid + " " + name + " " + password + "\n"); }
         * 
         * return strBuffer.toString();
         */
        }

    static class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        private Context context;

        // Defined Database Schema
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbname";
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "db_table";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
        private static final String COL_ID= "_id";
        private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
        private static final String COL_PASSWORD = "password";

        // List of Queries
        private static final String QUERY_CREATE_TABLE = 
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" 
                + COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
                + COL_NAME + " VARCHAR(250), " 
                + COL_PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(250)" +
                ");";

        private static final String QUERY_DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            this.context = context;
            Message.message(context, "constructer was called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                // CREATE TABLE ahamadssb_table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                // AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(255));
                db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE);
                Message.message(context, "onCreate was  called");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(QUERY_DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
                Message.message(context, "onUpgrade  was called");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Message.message(context, "" + e);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try reinstalling the app after completley uninstalling once..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't ask for the id column. Add it to your columns variable:

```
String[] columns = { SQLiteHelper.COL_ID, SQLiteHelper.COL_NAME, SQLiteHelper.COL_PASSWORD };
```

Comment: thanks, My mistake I was trying without "_id" at first and it was ok but later I included "_id" but I forgot to add it into the array

Comment: On this site, it's convention to mark answers as accepted (the check mark), not edit your question to include "(SOLVED)"

Answer (score 1):

You have to add "_id" column to projection array.
It is not present in projection so getColumnIndex returns -1

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)